# Selecting two tables and ranking

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm attempting to select two tables that have the same columns and combining them into 1 which will rank column `SalesAmount` from Highest to Lowest. I've attempted to do this by using `UNION ALL` but currently, the returned select is ranking them both separately.

`TableTwo` has a different `ReportId` value then the values in `TableOne`.

Here is an example of the returned select from `TableOne` statement:

| StateId | ReportTitle | ReportId | SalesAmount | SalesRank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Online Sales in California | 21 | 22 | 1 |
| 12 | Online Sales in New York | 21 | 13 | 2 |
| 23 | Online Sales in Nevada | 21 | 9 | 4 |

---

Here is an example of the returned select from `TableTwo` which only has 1 value:

| StateId | ReportTitle | ReportId | SalesAmount | SalesRank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14 | Online Sales in Michigan | 91 | 11 | 3 |

I am now attempting to combine these two tables and rank them accordingly. when using `UNION ALL` Here is what is being returned:

| StateId | ReportTitle | ReportId | SalesAmount | SalesRank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Online Sales in California | 21 | 22 | 1 |
| 12 | Online Sales in New York | 37 | 13 | 2 |
| 23 | Online Sales in Nevada | 14 | 9 | 4 |
| 14 | Online Sales in Michigan | 91 | 11 | 3 |

The row `Michigan` is ranked 3. It is selecting both tables into 1 statement but not ranking them as I am trying to do. How can I achieve this? My expected results is having both tables be Ordered By `SalesRank` appropriately

Here is an example of my expected result:

| StateId | ReportTitle | ReportId | SalesAmount | SalesRank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Online Sales in California | 21 | 22 | 1 |
| 12 | Online Sales in New York | 37 | 13 | 2 |
| 14 | Online Sales in Michigan | 91 | 11 | 3 |
| 23 | Online Sales in Nevada | 14 | 9 | 4 |

---

Here is a query of example:

```
CREATE TABLE TableOne
(
    StateId INT,
    ReportTitle VARCHAR(100),
    ReportId INT,
    SalesAmount Money, 
    SalesRank INT
)

INSERT INTO TableOne (StateId,ReportTitle,ReportId,SalesAmount, SalesRank)
VALUES (1,'Online Sales in California',21, 22, 1),(12,'Online Sales in New York ',21, 13, 1),  (1,'Online Sales in Nevada',21, 9, 4)

CREATE TABLE TableTwo
(
    StateId INT,
    ReportTitle VARCHAR(100),
    ReportId INT,
    SalesAmount Money, 
    SalesRank INT
)

INSERT INTO TableOne (StateId,ReportTitle,ReportId,SalesAmount, SalesRank)
VALUES (14,'Online Sales in Michigan',91, 11, 3)

SELECT * FROM TableOne 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM TableTwo
```

Comment: Your second insert is into TableOne - probably should be TableTwo. And you have inserted SalesRank 1 twice into TableOne.

Comment: Plus one for a well constructed question - even if it is trivial :)

Comment: Please clarify your question given the `ReportId` values expected do NOT match the example data above that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your attempt doesn't have an [`order by`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) clause? So of course it won't be ordered. Add `order by SalesRank` e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM TableOne 
UNION ALL 
SELECT *
FROM TableTwo
ORDER BY SalesRank
```

Note: Rows in tables are not stored or accessed in any determinable order. If order is important you must use an `order by` clause as part of your `select`.

Answer (score 2):

Generally I like to see the actual column names in a `SELECT` so I added those and an `ORDER BY` on the `SalesRank` - not sure if you want the default ascending or descending.

```
SELECT 
    StateId
    ReportTitle,
    ReportId,
    SalesAmount, 
    SalesRank 
FROM TableOne 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 
    StateId
    ReportTitle,
    ReportId,
    SalesAmount, 
    SalesRank 
FROM TableTwo
ORDER BY SalesRank;
```